# What do the profiler.out contents represent?

Tags: code-coverage, profiler, openedge, progress-4gl

I've been working on a script that retrieves test code-coverage data from a profiler.out file. Now generating this file wasn't much of an issue. But I can't seem to understand how the contents of this file relate to the test that were fired (to me these just look like random numbers and strings)...

Does anyone know what these numbers represent?

I've generated an example profiler-file (source language is Progress) that looks like this:

[Example Profiler Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poZjR.png)

Thanks in advance!

Jacco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenEdge Profiler is "lightly documented".  If you search the Progress kbase it will turn up several entries that eventually lead to:
 https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/1980.profiler-control-tool

This is the old unsupported stand-alone "profiler control tool" (the tool is unsupported, the profiler startup option and session handle are supported).

Inside the zip file that that page links to is the only known documentation of the profiler output format.

The current OpenEdge 11 IDE (PDSOE) has direct support for a profiler analysis tool.

The following code isn't very pretty but it is a stand-alone tool that reads a profiler output file (my preference is to name them "something.prf" rather than "profiler.out") and generates a report on the most time consuming lines of code:

```
/* zprof_topx.p
 *
 * process a .prf file and produce a report
 *
 * pro -p lib/zprof_topx.p -param tmp/f03e40c9-8043-0aba-e611-3cc5eac467bd.2016.12.18.11.12.14
 *
 * note: there is no ".prf" at the end of the file name!
 *
 */

define variable zprofData as character no-undo.
define variable topLines  as integer no-undo initial 20.

define temp-table tt_profile
  field id          as integer format ">>>>9"
  field pdate       as date format "99/99/99"
  field description as character format "x(30)"
  index profile-idx is unique primary
    id
  index profile-date
    pdate
.

define temp-table tt_source
  field id          as integer format ">>>>9"
  field pid         as integer format ">>>>>9"
  field pname       as character format "x(40)"
  field debug_name  as character format "x(40)"
  index source-idx is unique primary
    id pid
  index source-name
    pname
.

define temp-table tt_tree
  field id          as integer format ">>>>9"
  field caller      as integer format ">>>>>9"
  field src_line    as integer format ">>>>>9"
  field callee      as integer format ">>>>>9"
  field call_count  as integer format ">>>>>9"
  index tree-idx is primary
    id caller src_line callee
.

define temp-table tt_ptime
  field id          as integer format ">>>>9"
  field pid         as integer format ">>>>>9"
  field src_line    as integer format ">>>>>9"
  field exec_count  as integer format ">>>>>>>>>9"
  field exe_time    as decimal format ">>>>>9.999999"
  field tot_time    as decimal format ">>>>>9.999999"
  field avg_time    as decimal format ">>>>>9.999999"
  index ptime-idx is unique primary
    id pid src_line
  index avg-idx
    avg_time descending
  index line-idx
    src_line
  index ptime-pid-t1
    id pid exe_time
  index ptime-pid-t3
    id pid avg_time
  index ptime-t1
    id exe_time
  index ptime-t3
    id avg_time
.

define temp-table tt_code_line
  field pid         as integer   format ">>>>>9"        /* program id#              */
  field src_line    as integer   format ">>>>9"         /* source line#             */
  field pname       as character format "x(30)"         /* procedure or class name      */
  field ipname      as character format "x(40)"         /* internal procedure or method name    */
  field t1          as decimal   format ">>>>>9.999999"     /* execution time           */
  field t2          as integer   format ">>>>>>>>>9"        /* calls                */
  field t3          as integer   format ">>9"           /* sessions             */
  field t4          as decimal   format ">>>>>9.999999"     /* average time             */
  index bad-idx1 is unique primary
    pid pname src_line
  index bad-idx2
    t2 t3
  index bad-idx3
    t1
  index avg-idx
    t4
.


/*********************************************************/

define stream inStrm.

procedure zprofiler_load:

  define input parameter zprofData as character no-undo.

  define variable i   as integer   no-undo.
  define variable v   as integer   no-undo.
  define variable dt  as date      no-undo.
  define variable dsc as character no-undo.

  define variable profile_id as integer no-undo.

  empty temp-table tt_profile.
  empty temp-table tt_source.
  empty temp-table tt_tree.
  empty temp-table tt_ptime.

  file-info:file-name = zprofData + ".prf".

  if file-info:full-pathname = ? then
    do:
      message "Cannot find profiler .prf data file:" zprofData.
      pause.
      return.
    end.

  /* message "loading from:" file-info:full-pathname. /* session:date-format. */ pause. */

  input stream inStrm from value( file-info:full-pathname ).

  i = 1.

  repeat:               /* in theory there could be more than 1?  that would probably break a lot of stuff...   */

    import stream inStrm v /* dt */ ^ dsc no-error.     /* the profiler apparently ignores session:date-format...   */

    if v <> 1 then
      do:
        input stream inStrm close.
        message "Invalid version:" v.
        pause.
        return.
      end.

    /* message v dt dsc. pause. */              /* the profiler apparently ignores session:date-format...   */

    profile_id = i.

    create tt_profile.
    assign
      tt_profile.id          = profile_id
      tt_profile.pdate       = today /* dt */
      tt_profile.description = dsc
    .

    i = i + 1.

  end.

  /* message "profile id:" profile_id. pause. */

  i = 1.

  repeat:

      create tt_source.
      tt_source.id = profile_id.
      import stream inStrm tt_source.pid tt_source.pname tt_source.debug_name no-error.

      i = i + 1.

  end.

/*  message i "tt_source loaded". pause.
 *  message "creating tt_source session record". pause.
 */

  /* create tt_source. */       /* don't CREATE -- an extra will be left over from the REPEAT logic */
  assign
    tt_source.id = profile_id
    tt_source.pid = 0
    tt_source.pname = "Session"
    tt_source.debug_name = "Session"
  .

  /* message "tt_source session record created". pause. */

  i = 1.

  repeat:

    create tt_tree.
    tt_tree.id = profile_id.
    import stream inStrm tt_tree.caller tt_tree.src_line tt_tree.callee tt_tree.call_count no-error.

    i = i + 1.

  end.

  delete tt_tree.

  /* message i "tt_tree loaded". pause. */

  i = 1.

  repeat:


    create tt_ptime.
    tt_ptime.id = profile_id.
    import stream inStrm tt_ptime.pid tt_ptime.src_line tt_ptime.exec_count tt_ptime.exe_time tt_ptime.tot_time no-error.
    tt_ptime.avg_time = tt_ptime.exe_time / tt_ptime.exec_count.

    i = i + 1.

  end.

  delete tt_ptime.

  /* message i "tt_ptime loaded". pause. */

  input stream inStrm close.

  return.

end.


procedure zprofiler_proc:

  define variable c  as integer no-undo.
  define variable i  as integer no-undo.
  define variable t1 as decimal no-undo format ">>>>>9.999999".
  define variable t2 as integer no-undo format ">>>>>>>>>9".
  define variable t3 as integer no-undo format ">>9".

  define variable srcName    as character no-undo.
  define variable iprocName  as character no-undo.

  empty temp-table tt_code_line.

  for each tt_ptime no-lock by tt_ptime.avg_time descending:     

    /*  if exec_count < 1 /* or src_line = 0 */ then next. */

    find tt_source where
         tt_source.id =  tt_ptime.id and
         tt_source.pid = tt_ptime.pid no-error.

    if not available( tt_source ) then
      srcName = "session".
     else
      srcName = tt_source.pname.

    if srcName begins "lib/zprof" then next.            /* don't include the profiler */

    find tt_code_line where
         tt_code_line.pid      = tt_ptime.pid and
         tt_code_line.src_line = tt_ptime.src_line and
         tt_code_line.pname    = srcName /* tt_source.pname */ no-error.

    if not available tt_code_line then
      do:
        create tt_code_line.
        assign
          i = i + 1
          tt_code_line.pid      = tt_ptime.pid
          tt_code_line.src_line = tt_ptime.src_line
          tt_code_line.pname    = srcName
        .
      end.

  end.

  /* message i "entries processed". pause. */

  for each tt_code_line:

    assign
      tt_code_line.t1 = 0
      tt_code_line.t2 = 0
    .

    for
      each tt_source where
        tt_source.pname = tt_code_line.pname,
      each tt_ptime where
        tt_ptime.id       = tt_source.id  and
        tt_ptime.pid      = tt_source.pid and
        tt_ptime.src_line = tt_code_line.src_line:      

      assign
        tt_code_line.t1 = tt_code_line.t1 + tt_ptime.exe_time
        tt_code_line.t2 = tt_code_line.t2 + tt_ptime.exec_count
        tt_code_line.t3 = tt_code_line.t3 + 1
      .

      if tt_ptime.pid = 0 and tt_ptime.src_line = 0 then tt_code_line.t1 = tt_ptime.tot_time.

    end.

  end.

  for each tt_code_line:

    tt_code_line.t4 = ( tt_code_line.t1 / tt_code_line.t2 ).    /* calculate the average time... */

    if num-entries( tt_code_line.pname, " " ) > 1 then
      assign
        tt_code_line.ipname = entry( 1, tt_code_line.pname, " " )
        tt_code_line.pname  = entry( 2, tt_code_line.pname, " " )
      .

  end.

  return.

end.


procedure zprofiler_topx:

  define input parameter zprofData as character no-undo.
  define input parameter toTTY     as logical   no-undo.
  define input parameter topLines  as integer   no-undo.

  define variable c  as integer no-undo.
  define variable i  as integer no-undo.
  define variable t1 as decimal no-undo format ">>>>>9.999999".
  define variable t2 as integer no-undo format ">>>>>>>>>9".
  define variable t3 as integer no-undo format ">>9".

  define variable t9 as integer no-undo.

  find first tt_profile no-lock no-error.   /* assuming that they're all the same date... */

  for each tt_code_line no-lock where tt_code_line.pname <> "session":
    t9 = t9 + tt_code_line.t1.
  end.

  if toTTY = no then output to value( zprofData + ".rpt" ).

  display
    tt_profile.description  label "Description" format "x(70)" skip
    "Session Total Execution Time  " string( t9, "hh:mm:ss" )  skip
    "Line 0 = initialization, line -1 = cleanup"               skip
   with frame prof-hdr
     title " Profiler: Top Results "
     width 120
     centered
     overlay
     side-labels
     row 4
  .

  i = 0.

  for each tt_code_line no-lock by tt_code_line.t1 descending:

    if tt_code_line.pname = "session" then next.

    i = i + 1.

    display
      tt_code_line.pname    label "Program/Class"
      tt_code_line.src_line label "Line"
      tt_code_line.t1       label "Time"
      tt_code_line.t4       label "Avg Time"
      tt_code_line.t2       label "Calls"
      tt_code_line.ipname   label "Internal Procedure/Method"
     with frame prof-rpt
       title " Top Lines: Total Execution Time "
       width 120
       centered
       overlay
       down
       row 9
    .

    if i > topLines then leave.

  end.

  if toTTY = no then
    output close.
   else
    do:
      pause.
      hide frame prof-rpt.
      hide frame prof-hdr.
    end.

  return.

end.


/* main body
 *
 */

zprofData = entry( 1, session:parameter, "|" ).
if num-entries( session:parameter, "|" ) = 2 then topLines = integer( entry( 2, session:parameter, "|" )).

run zprofiler_load( zprofData ).            /* load profiler data into temp-tables to analyze       */
run zprofiler_proc.                 /* process the data                     */
run zprofiler_topx( zprofData, no,  topLines ).     /* report on the top X execution time lines -- to file      */

if session:batch = no then
  run zprofiler_topx( zprofData, yes, topLines ).   /* report on the top X execution time lines -- to TTY       */

quit.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the ANTLR4 grammar for the profiler output here: [Link](https://github.com/Riverside-Software/sonar-openedge/blob/develop/profiler-parser/src/main/antlr4/eu/rssw/antlr/profiler/ProfilerGrammar.g4).

The commercial edition of the [OpenEdge plugin for SonarQube](https://github.com/Riverside-Software/sonar-openedge) already has a code coverage functionality. Here is an example of the code coverage on newly committed code in a Git repository (that's a demo project): [Link](http://sonar.riverside-software.fr/component_measures?id=RSSW%3ATestProject&metric=new_coverage)

Disclaimer: I work for Riverside Software

Comment: Yes, I found the commercial edition (during the evaluation license) very useful. But our company hasn't yet decided to purchase a full subscription due to its pricing... Thanks for your answer anyway!